# How to deploy a topology on Apache Storm Nimbus deployed on AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-ecs, apache-storm

I have succeeded deploying an Apache Storm cluster on AWS ECS after a long trial and error process.

Now, I am wondering how could I deploy a topology on its Nimbus node?
Should bundle the topology deployment process with Nimbus process in docker's ENTREYPOINT?
What if I want deployment be on demand?